# Partial Screen Capture using C#

Tags: c#, screenshot

I need to create an application in C# that captures part of the screen when certain part of the same screen changes. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class. It has a CopyFromScreen method that will draw the content of a rectangular area of the screen into a Bitmap object.

It should do what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this open source project called - [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/).  It is developed using C#.
Download the source code and have a look at it, you will get the basic idea of using System.Drawing classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
  g.CopyFromScreen(Left, Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size,  CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
  bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```